# How to delete all animation from an appended file?

Tags: animation

So, I have appended a file to a blender scene, and now I want to delete all the animation from the previous appended scene. I have tried going into the dope sheet, selecting all keyframes with <kbd>A</kbd> and hitting <kbd>X</kbd>, but to no avail. Any tips/is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible the channels are locked / protected?

You can click the lock icon to toggle this, or press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while your cursor is hovering over the channel.

[image: Locking and unlocking a channel]

Comment: They were! I'm an idiot ahah

Comment: @Maria Glad you got it solved! Mind accepting my answer, since it seems it was the solution to your problem?